# Vue select not binding to the model

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

I have a simple `select` element in VueJS:

```
<select v-model="country" class="dropdown-input">
  <option
    v-for="c in countries"
    v-bind:key="c.CountryCode"
    v-bind:value="c.CountryCode"
    >{{c.Country}}</option>
</select>
```

The data looks like this:

```
  data() {
    return {
      country: { CountryCode: 'GB', Country: 'United Kingdom' },
      countries: [
        { CountryCode: 'GB', Country: 'United Kingdom' },
        { CountryCode: 'FR', Country: 'France' }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But when I replace `this.countries` and `this.country` with (respectively) a list of objects and an object (in the same format as above) the `select` does not show the selected item. It was doing this when the list was a simple list of `string` and `this.country` was a simple `string`.

Is there something extra I need to do to get the `select` element showing the "selected" item programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer in this [github post](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/308#issuecomment-314276628)...

In my case the `select` definition needs to be:

```
<select v-model="country" class="dropdown-input">
  <option
    v-for="c in countries"
    v-bind:key="c.CountryCode"
    v-bind:value="c"
    >{{c.Country}}</option>
</select>
```

Specifically, that the `v-bind:value` must be matching an object from the list, rather than the key.

This makes sense, because the `v-model` value will be an object, which is what the `v-bind:value` is matched against.